# simple html DOM cant see all hrefs

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

Im trying to retrieve the youtube link of a certain site. But when using the simple html DOM parser it cant find the links im looking for.

```
$new_html = file_get_html("https://www.bia2.com/video/Amir-Shamloo/Delam-Tange/");
    foreach ($new_html->find('href') as $youtube) {
    echo $youtube;
}
```

it should find the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJ2aNG0aJPU.

does someone know what the problem is here?

Comment: That youtube link doesn't seem to appear in the source code.

Comment: also this may fail because of invalid html

Comment: If it's an embedded video it probably uses a link like this: https://www.youtube.com/embed/vJ2aNG0aJPU not the watch?v= version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular link is inserted via JavaScript via `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady("vJ2aNG0aJPU")` during the `onload` event.

SimpleHtmlDom (or any other PHP based HTML parser for that matter) will not execute any JavaScript. They just parse the markup returned by the webserver.

**You'd need a scraper capable of executing Javascript before you can scrape it. Or you can match the argument to that function and assemble the link yourself.**

On a side note: `$new_html->find('href')` will try to find any *elements* named "href", which is obviously wrong. To get all href attributes for any element, you'd have to use `*[href]` instead.

On another side not: SimpleHtmlDom is a crap library. Consider your options:

- [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php/3577662)

Comment: Ty it seems that this is indeed the problem.

Comment: Im looking around for something what can help me but cant really find it. do you know something what can execute js before my simple dom parser retrieves the hrefs

Comment: @wouter.lilopel not in PHP. You will likely need to look into a nodejs solution instead (http://phantomjs.org). Or you just match the ID as suggested.

Comment: what do you mean with match the ID can you give a example of that?

Comment: the preg_match_all is still a bit confusing im trying to do the same for https://www.bia2.com/video/ but it takes way to much im trying to get the links of the diverant video pages i used this '#a href="/video/(.*)"#' but i get some extras i dont want